# Dissapearing cycles when profiling

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling

I'm optimizing some c++ code and have so far made good progress, but now I'm confused. When running the application in the XCode Time profiler the two largest functions combined only claim about 55% of the cycles, the rest is some 1-3%:ers totaling maybe 65% of the cpu cycles.

The code base is rather standard, a couple of thousand objects with virtual calls. Nothing special, no special patterns. Code style you've seen many times before.

Any tips or suggestions where they might have been used, or how to find out?

Comment: what profiler do you use?

Comment: The question indicates the problem. You're looking for functions that take lots of cycles. I suspect you mean exclusive time, which is the least useful. Plenty of people rely on [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771), which is about getting a more complete understanding of *why* time is spent, not *where*.

Comment: @cageman The Time profiler, edited into the Q as well.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Interesting read, I'll give that a try.